# 要素Aの数字より要素Bの数字が小さい場合に、要素Cに判定を出したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

以下のような予算(`class="budget"`)を費用(`class="cost"`)が上回った場合に判定結果(`class="result"`)に「予算オーバー」と表示したいですが上手くいきません。
ご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

▼HTML

```
<div>
    <div><span class="budget">100</span>　<span class="cost">80</span>　<span class="result"></span></div>
    <div><span class="budget">50</span>　<span class="cost">70</span>　<span class="result"></span></div>
    <div><span class="budget">30</span>　<span class="cost">50</span>　<span class="result"></span></div>
</div>
```

▼試したコード

```
<script>
var budget = $('.budget').text();
var cost = $('.cost').text();
if(budget < cost) {
  $('.result').text('予算オーバー');
}
</script>
```

▼理想の結果

```
100　80　
50　70　予算オーバー
30　50　予算オーバー
```

▼現状の結果

```
100　80　予算オーバー
50　70　予算オーバー
30　50　予算オーバー
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

要素は複数あるので、配列に格納して同じインデックスで比較します。

```js
  <script>
    const budget = $('.budget').map((_, e) => Number(e.innerText)).get();
    const cost = $('.cost').map((_, e) => Number(e.innerText)).get();
    $('.result').each((i, e) => {
        if (budget[i] < cost[i]) {
            e.innerText = '予算オーバー';
        }
    });
  </script>
```